# Regular expression for replacing word in text that skips sections of text

Tags: regex

I have the below HTML file (simplified code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
...

<body>
  This is my header!
  {% include "header.tpl.html"%}
</body>

</html>
```

And I have the below code snippet in JS that is supposed to replace all occurences of "header" in the HTML:

```
const v = 'header';
let re = new RegExp(`${v}`, 'gi');
fileStr = fileStr.replace(re, '{% test %}');
```

As I result, I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
...

<body>
  This is my {% test %}!
  {% include "{% test %}.tpl.html"%}
</body>

</html>
```

So, the first {% test %} replaced works as expected, but the regular expression also detects occurrences inside curly brackets, which messes up my template.

How do I build a regular expression that skips all text between {% and %} markers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the strings inside`{%...%}` and capture them in order to be able to skip them:

```js
var fileStr = ' This is my header!\n  {% include "header.tpl.html"%}';
let v = 'header';
let re = new RegExp(`({%[^]*?%})|${v}`, 'gi');
fileStr = fileStr.replace(re, (x,y) => y || `{% test %}`);
console.log(fileStr);
```

The `({%[^]*?%})|header` pattern matches and captures `{%` + zero or more chars as few as possible, and then `%}` into Group 1, or matches `header` string in a case insensitive way in any other context.

Then, if Group 1 matches, the replacement is the Group 1 value, so the `{%...%}` substrings are kept as is, and then `header` is replaced with `test`.

You may also use

```js
let re = new RegExp(`({%[^]*?%})|\\b${v}\\b`, 'gi');
```

to replace whole words only (but only if these words have no special chars, otherwise, you would need other types of boundaries).

Comment: This is very good. How would you modify the regex to exclude HTML tags as well? (for example <header>)

Comment: @Miki ``let re = new RegExp(`(<[^>]*>|{%[^]*?%})|\\b${v}\\b`, 'gi');``

Comment: Thanks. I think there is an extra back slash next to \b. Also, this regex will exclude anything between symbols, like <a>header</a>, that should not be excluded.

Comment: @Miki Did you *try* it?

Comment: It actually works as spec'ed - thanks, not sure what was broken on my end.